# Error 403 Forbidden - After a corrupted uninstall of Live_Chat module

Tags: http-status-code-403, odoo-10

I have been testing odoo for about 2 weeks now, my site is kind of up and run when I tried to uninstall Live_chat module, everything seems broken to part ... I have quite a lot of data on my test_odoo_machine, so it is greatly appreciated if someone could help me out.

Instead of install odoo on ubuntu or windows like most other people, I wanted to try something different so i go with DOCKER_VERSION of odoo.. everything was working fine until i tried to uninstall live_chat module, everything stop workings and I have been searching, searching and searching for solution but without lucks.

Could someone please help me, here is the log:

```
24 10:53:14,202 1 [1;32m[1;49mINFO[0m edh_vietnam werkzeug: 172.17.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2017 10:53:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 24 10:53:14,210 1 [1;31m[1;49mERROR[0m edh_vietnam werkzeug: Error on request:

k (most recent call last):

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi self.server.app)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute ion_iter = app(environ, start_response)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 246, in app elf.app(e, s)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application pplication_unproxied(environ, start_response)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied handler(environ, start_response)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1306, in __call__ elf.dispatch(environ, start_response)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1280, in __call__ elf.app(environ, start_wrapped)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__ elf.app(environ, start_response)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1471, in dispatch ir_http._dispatch()

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 191, in _dispatch url_lang and request.website_multilang and request.lang != request.website.default_lang_code)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 869, in __get__ ermine_value(record)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 971, in determine_value prefetch_field(self)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3056, in _prefetch_field records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 2996, in read ad_from_database(stored, inherited)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3124, in _read_from_database te(query_str, params)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper

(self, *args, **kwargs)

sr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 218, in execute lf._obj.execute(query, params)

ingError: column website.channel_id does not exist

...d","website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube","website"....

24 10:53:14,484 1 [1;32m[1;49mINFO[0m edh_vietnam odoo.sql_db: bad query: SELECT "website"."company_id" as "company_id","website"."social_linkedin" as "social_linkedin","website"."id" as "id","website"."compress_html" as "compress_html","website"."google_analytics_key" as "google_analytics_key","website"."create_uid" as "create_uid","website"."cdn_activated" as "cdn_activated","website"."default_lang_id" as "default_lang_id","website"."website_form_enable_metadata" as "website_form_enable_metadata","website"."name" as "name","website"."write_uid" as "write_uid","website"."social_youtube" as "social_youtube","website"."channel_id" as "channel_id","website"."social_twitter" as "social_twitter","website"."domain" as "domain","website"."user_id" as "user_id","website"."cdn_filters" as "cdn_filters","website"."social_facebook" as "social_facebook","website"."cdn_url" as "cdn_url","website"."create_date" as "create_date","website"."social_github" as "social_github","website"."default_lang_code" as "default_lang_code","website"."write_date" as "write_date","website"."social_googleplus" as "social_googleplus" FROM "website"

ebsite".id IN (1) ORDER BY "website"."id"
```